# IPad--how to refresh subview on ipad?

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiscrollview, reloaddata

I add 4 subviews(UIScrollView,UITableView)in main view on ipad,  and  each view has it own data.
In Marco view, I try to reload data from server every 3 second to refresh my Marco View.
as first pic..
[image]

I set 3 Marco icons on ipad main view, when I delete one on popoverView.
Icons on popoverView really delete, but still show up 3 icons on main view.
as second and third pic...
[image]

[image]

It must be delete from background and then open app it gonna be correct view..
as fourth pic..
Dose any one know what's problem..  I try to use `[marco_scrollview setNeedsDisplay]` .
but it no work..
Thank in advance..
here is my code to get Marcodata:

```
- (void)getTheMacroURLData{
    //[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
//    [marco_scrollview setNeedsDisplay];
    self.macroList = nil;
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    EnvoTouchAppDelegate *appDelegate = (EnvoTouchAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    struct sockaddr_in Addr;
    bzero(&Addr, sizeof(Addr));
    Addr.sin_len = sizeof(Addr);
    Addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef target = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(NULL, (struct sockaddr *) &Addr);
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(target, &flags);
    if (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN){
        //Serial Number not save in the keychain now
        NSString *theNewURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:eGetAllMacrosSettingURL3G,[userDefaults objectForKey:@"ecsn"],appDelegate.udid];
        NSURL *theNewURL = [NSURL URLWithString:theNewURLString];
        self.macroList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:theNewURL];
    }
    if (flags & kSCNetworkFlagsReachable){
        NSString *theNewURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:eGetAllMacrosSettingURLWiFi,appDelegate.ipString,appDelegate.udid];
        NSURL *theNewURL = [NSURL URLWithString:theNewURLString];
        self.macroList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:theNewURL];
    }
    int k=0;
    for (int i=0; i<[self.macroList count]; i++) {
        int j=i%9;
        if (j==0) {
            k++;
        }
        UIButton *iconButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        NSString *picString = [[self.macroList objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey: @"pid"];
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:picString];

        [iconButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [iconButton setTag:i];
        [iconButton addTarget:self action:@selector(exeMacro:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
        [iconButton setFrame:CGRectMake(30+(i%9*80), 17+((k-1)*70), 48, 48)];   
        //[self.view addSubview:iconButton];
        [marco_scrollview addSubview:iconButton];
        if ([self.macroList count] > 18) {
            [marco_scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 525 + (([self.macroList count]/4 - 4) * 70) )];
        }
    }
    [marco_view addSubview:marco_scrollview];
}
```

And I try to reload data every 3 second..
I dont know why it doesn't refresh Marco View..

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code that drives the display of the Marco scrollview?

Comment: I post my code about Marco scrollview..Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The display makes it appear as if you are using a tableview somewhere. If so, are you calling the reloadData method on the table view?